# 'atomic_uint32_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have the following line in my code:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_uint32_t tmp;
```

However, I am getting the  following compilation error:

> 'atomic_uint32_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type.

I included `<cstdint>` but the error persists.

My GCC version: 5.4.0, Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

Comment: @MikelF Thanks...I corrected it.

Comment: Did you include <atomic> header file?

Comment: @Asesh Yes, I already did  that.

Comment: http://wg21.link/lwg2441

Comment: It's still in working paper, not finalized yet. It's likely shipped with gcc 7. For now, use `std::atomic<std::uint32_t>`

Comment: The first commit ever to introduce it to gcc was committed in [2016-07-20](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/650853/), gcc 5.4 was shipped by 2016-06-03

Comment: @Danh Thanks for the information. I corrected it and now it is compiling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per Danh's comment, I used

```
std::atomic<std::uint32_t>
```

and voila, it is  working now. Thanks Danh.

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't forget the `std::` namespace prefix in C++!

If you're trying to use the `atomic_*` alias types, such as:

1. `atomic_bool` instead of `std::atomic<bool>`
2. `atomic_uint_least32_t` instead of `std::atomic<std::uint_least32_t>`
3. `atomic_int_least32_t` instead of `std::atomic<std::int_least32_t>`
4. etc.

..and you are getting this error, then **you need to prefix each type with `std::`!** Ex: `std::atomic_bool`, `std::atomic_uint_least32_t`, etc.

#### How to share `atomic_*` types in source code which compiles in both C *and* C++

If you are trying to share some source code snippets with C, however, so that they can compile in C *or* C++, then you cannot prefix C source code variables with `std::`. In that case, you should add `using namespace std` for C++ compilation, like this.

This type of layout can compile in *both* C and C++:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include <atomic> // for `atomic_*` types in C++
    // This is required for C++ since all `atomic_*` type aliases are in namespace `std`, as in
    // `std::atomic_bool`, for instance, instead of just `atomic_bool`!
    using namespace std;
#else
    #include <stdatomic.h> // for `atomic_*` types in C
#endif

atomic_uint_fast32_t u1 = 12345;
```

Or, *even better*, don't pollute the whole namespace with `using namespace std;`. Instead, just alias the few types you specifically need, like this:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include <atomic> // for `atomic_*` types in C++
    // This is required for C++ since all `atomic_*` type aliases are in namespace `std`, as in
    // `std::atomic_bool`, for instance, instead of just `atomic_bool`!
    // using all of namespace std is overkill; just do this instead:
    using atomic_int = std::atomic_int;
    using atomic_size_t = std::atomic_size_t;
#else
    #include <stdatomic.h> // for `atomic_*` types in C
#endif
```

See an example of this in my [atomic_types.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/atomic_types.c) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.